# How to set day of year as ticklabels for several years?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently working with some temperature data from a sensor that was active for about 4 months (from December 2018 to March 2019). I'm trying to plot the data; however, my time series currently goes from 350 to 430. How do I make the x-axis ticks start over at 0 once it reaches 365? Or, how can I add ticks that represent months starting at December and going to March?

Current graph:
[image]

Comment: You can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have your `matplotlib.pyplot` object, e.g. `plt`. We can use this to change the labels of the x-axis ticks:

```
xticks = plt.xticks()[0]
plt.xticks(xticks, (xticks % 365))
```

Comment: The question is a bit, is there a 0th day of the year?

Comment: The 0th day is January 1st. If indexing should begin with 1, you can modify the label portion to be `(xticks % 365) + 1` since `xticks` is an `ndarray`. There's also a 366 days in some years, so this won't be accurate for leap years.